# If file exist then include on all files

Tags: php

I am fairly new to PHP and I was wondering if it is possible to put an "if file exists then include" all files listed.  I am using different HTML templates and some of them don't include code that is being interpreted by an PHP file.

EDIT: Please up-vote and down-vote the comments because I have no idea which answer to use.

Comment: What are you trying to include and where?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a file to be included before any code runs by using the auto_prepend_file ini setting. If you're using PHP through CGI you may be able to set this up by adding a php.ini in the directory you're running your scripts from and then adding

```
auto_prepend_file = ../prepend.php
```

.. to automagically have ../prepend.php inserted and parsed before any other file.

If you're using the regular PHP Apache module, you can set it up in .htaccess if your server allows overriding PHP values in your .htaccess:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file ../prepend.php
```

And if you want to avoid using an .htaccess file, you can also set the configuration in the  directive.

This does require that the file you're talking about will get parsed as PHP (otherwise the configuration value for PHP won't do anything, as PHP isn't loaded or initialized for the request).

Answer (score 1):

the *include* statement differs from the *require* statement that it only generates a warning (rather than an error), which could be silenced with the *@* operator.

However, I'd recommend getting used to error handling... writing a template engine isn't that hard in PHP... This one is about the shortest:

```
class Template {
  private $_scriptPath=TEMPLATE_PATH;//comes from config.php
  public function setScriptPath($scriptPath){
      $this->_scriptPath=$scriptPath;
  }
  public function render($filename){

      ob_start();
      if(file_exists($this->_scriptPath.$filename)){
          include($this->_scriptPath.$filename);
      } else throw new TemplateNotFoundException();
      return ob_get_clean();
  }
}
```

Use it like

```
$v = new Template();
$v->someProperty="value";
$v->render('myview.php');
```

(Albeit this still has problems with non-existing properties (works, but will throw warnings), for that you'll need so-called magic functions like __set and __get)

As for not having any PHP code in an HTML, it doesn't matter for PHP... it'll just show the HTML instead. But you'll quickly move to frameworks hopefully..

Answer (score 0):

PHP gives us some tools to test if a file exists or not.

1. [`is_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) — Tells whether the filename is a regular file
2. [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) — Checks whether a file or directory exists

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function include_if_exists($path) {
    if( @file_exists($path) && is_file($path) ) {
        include($path);
    }
}

include_if_exists("lib/mylibrary.php");

//...
```

You can also use an autoloader to search for class library files, depending on what it is you are trying to accomplish.  See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: Ah, you say it's for templating.  The solution I posted is more for library loading.  I concur with @Aadaam on writing a templating library.

Comment: But if your problem is that an HTML template includes some PHP code that references a class that you didn't include, then autoloading is what you want.